# Get every two rows from data table to result

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, rows

I have a table with multilanguage strings as follows:

```
type_id_fk  lang_id_fk  ui_text   
1           1           "Faktúra"
1           2           "Invoice"
2           1           "Dodací list"
2           2           "Bill of delivery"
3           1           "Objednávka"
3           2           "Order sheet"
```

I would like a select that generates this result:

```
1;"Faktúra";"Invoice"
2;"Dodací list";"Bill of delivery"
3;"Objednávka";"Order sheet"
```

where, 1,2,3 is from `type_id_fk`. I tried Group by, but not successfuly. Or tried something like this:

```
SELECT (t_type.type_id as typeID) ||';'||(
    SELECT t_type_ml.type_name FROM t_type_ml WHERE t_type_ml.type_id_fk = typeID AND t_type_ml.language_id_fk = 1)||';'||(
    SELECT t_type_ml.type_name FROM t_type_ml WHERE t_type_ml.type_id_fk = typeID AND t_type_ml.language_id_fk = 2)||';'
FROM t_type;
```

but it didnt even run. Do I need the join? Thanks for help

Comment: If you can, you would benefit greatly from normalizing your database schema.

Comment: What you need is something like this: http://postgres.cz/wiki/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks#MySQL_function_group_concat_in_PostgreSQL

@Dan, I am not sure what isn't normalized about his structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the aggregate function [`string_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE):

```
SELECT type_id_fk, string_agg(ui_text, ';' ORDER BY lang_id_fk)
FROM   t_type
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

The added `ORDER BY lang_id_fk` sorts according to `lang_id_fk` within the aggregated string.
This works for *any* number of languages, not just the special case of two.

Or, if you in fact want a single string per row:

```
SELECT type_id_fk::text || ';' 
       || COALESCE(string_agg(ui_text, ';' ORDER BY lang_id_fk), 'no text')
...
```

[`COALESCE()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) handles `NULL` values, should there be any.

Comment: +1 thanks, thats is working fine, i will need postgresql function, but as i dont expect to port to other db system, its now ok :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.type_id||';'||t1.type_name||';'||t2.type_name
FROM t_type t1 LEFT JOIN t_type t2 ON t1.type_id=t2.type_id AND t2.language_id_fk = 2
WHERE t1.language_id_fk = 1
```

Comment: That will work but not if there are more than two language entries.

Comment: thats true... it even doesnt work when one of two translation is not present, i will have to remember that, but for now its ok

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could pivot the data, something like:-

```
SELECT  TYPE_ID,
    MAX(CASE LANGUAGE_ID WHEN 1 THEN UI_TEXT ELSE NULL END) AS FRENCH,
    MAX(CASE LANGUAGE_ID WHEN 2 THEN UI_TEXT ELSE NULL END AS ENGLISH
FROM    TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY TYPE_ID
```